# generation of symmetric group of prime degree

Tags: group-theory, permutations, finite-groups, symmetric-groups

Let $p$ be a prime, $a=(1,2,...,p)$, $b$ is an odd permutation satisfying $b^{-1}ab\notin \langle a \rangle$ in $S_p$, I found that $\langle a,b \rangle$ is always the symmetric group $S_p$ when p is small ($p \leq 23$, use GAP and Magma), but I have no idea to prove it. Is it always true? Can you prove it or find a counterexample for it? Thanks for any help!

Comment: I chekced using the primitive groups database that this is true for all $p < 4095$. I expect the only way you could prove it would be to use the result that transitive groups of prime degree either have a normal Sylow $p$-subgroup or they are $2$-transitive, and then use the classification of $2$-transitive groups.

Comment: @DerekHolt: I found a paper https://doi.org/10.1112/jlms/s2-5.2.202 proved that if G is an insoluable group of prime degree contains an odd permutation then G is 3-fold transitive. Is it true that all 3-transitive insoluable groups of prime degree are simple?

Comment: And it's true for fermat prime degree, https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-662-21571-5_55 it seems imply the answer of this problem is true if we use the classification of 2-transitive groups and these conclusions.

Comment: No of course not, for example $S_n$ is not simple, and neither is ${\rm P \Gamma L}(2,16)$. But you are correct, assuming the classification of $3$-transitive groups, this implies that the result is true.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(Edited from the previous versions, which had many mistakes. The answer to the question seems to be yes.)

See "Jones, Gareth A. Cyclic regular subgroups of primitive permutation groups. J. Group Theory 5 (2002), no. 4, 403-407." for a classification of primitive subgroups of $S_n$ containing an $n$-cycle.

The groups $G$ that occur in the classification are the following:

(1.) $G = A_n$, $G = S_n$

(2.) $C_p \leq G \leq AGL_1(p)$

(3.) $G = PSL_2(11)$, $G = M_{11}$, $G = M_{23}$.

(4.) $PSL_d(q) \leq G \leq P \Gamma L_d(q)$ with $n = (q^d - 1)/(q-1)$.

To prove the result you claim, you should check that when $n$ is prime, in cases (3.) and (4.) you have $G \leq A_n$. For (3.) you have $G \leq A_n$ since $G$ is simple.

So the only interesting case is $G = P \Gamma L_d(q)$ in $S_n$ with $n = (q^d -1)/(q-1)$. We can assume that $PSL_d(q)$ is non-abelian simple, which holds if $d > 2$ or $q > 3$. Let's prove:

---

**Lemma:** $PGL_d(q) \leq A_n$ if and only if $d$ is odd or $q$ is even.

**Proof:** Let $\xi \in \mathbb{F}_q$ be a primitive element. We have $PGL_d(q) = \langle PSL_d(q), x \rangle$, where $x$ is the image of a diagonal matrix $diag(\xi,1,\ldots,1)$ in $PGL_d(q)$. Here $PSL_d(q) \leq A_n$ since it is simple, so we need to check when $x \in A_n$.

The cycle decomposition of $x$ consists of $(q^{d-1} -1)/(q-1) = 1 + q + \cdots + q^{d-2}$ cycles of length $q-1$. Hence $x \in A_n$ if and only if $d$ is odd or $q$ is even.

---

In the case where $n = (q^d -1)/(q-1)$ is prime we have $d$ odd, so in that case $PGL_d(q) \leq A_n$.

Then $P \Gamma L_d(q) = \langle PGL_d(q), \phi \rangle$, where $\phi$ is a field automorphism. The order of $\phi$ is $e$, where $q = p^e$ with $p$ prime. For $n = (p^{ed} -1)/(p^e - 1)$ to be prime $e$ must be odd. So $\phi$ has odd order, implying $\phi \in A_n$ and $P \Gamma L_d(q) \leq A_n$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Oh right, I missed the fact that $b$ was assumed to be an odd permutation. The paper mentioned in the answer could probably still be used to settle the question

Comment: So in your example with ${\rm P \Gamma L}(3,3)$ and $n=13$, the element $x$ has $5$ fixed point, and $x \in A_n$. We know that there are no examples with $n < 4096$. I am very confident that ${\rm P \Gamma L}(d,q) < A_n$ whenever $n$ is prime, but I haven't proved it yet.

Comment: @DerekHolt: You are right, that was incorrect (and there were many other mistakes in my earlier edits/comments). I edited to something which I hope is correct..